# javascript variable scope

Tags: javascript, jquery, variables, scope

I have the below code,

it is running however the output in the console is

> instant: true
>   instant2: false

as the variable is not being overwritten in the global scope.
How can I access the variable in the global scope?

```
var instant = false;
$('document').ready(function(){
  chrome.extension.sendRequest({
    action: "getStorage",
    key: "instant"
  }, function(response) {
    instant = true;
    console.log('instant: ', instant); 
  });
  console.log('instant2: ', instant);
});
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

It is getting overridden, but later. Your `function(response)` isn't getting executed until after the outer function returns.

Comment: It depends what you are trying to do. If you want a local version of instant, declare it with `var`, i.e. `var instant = true;`.

Comment: Actually I just want to use the variable in a global scope after this has completed.

Comment: What I am doing at the moment to fix it is to move all other code inside of the callback. but it is messy.

Answer (score 0):

`window.instant` should get you the value of your global variable.

Comment: Not after the line `instant = true` is executed. Without `var` preceding it, that will overwrite the global variable.